# MS Terminal Server/firewall usage query

Tags: firewall, terminal-server, reporting

I am using Terminal Server with 100 users connected via IP address 192.168.1.10

The Terminal server is also connected to a firewall which reports on websites opened and volumes of data downloaded

I'd like the reporting on individual users web usage (sites, data downloaded etc), I believe content filtering is not supported via Terminal Server.

Please could you help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to crop up a lot. I have used the SQUID open source web proxy to deal with this problem. SQUID doesn't load the server much so you could install it on the terminal server. Use a group policy to set IE to use the proxy server. See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/squid27setup.asp for my walkthrough of configuring SQUID.

JR

Answer (score 0):

You could install a proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) with authentification to access Internet website. You will have logs with username / url / size for each request and a lot of tools exist to make report base on these logs (look [here](http://www.squid-cache.org/Scripts/), sarg is quite good).

Answer (score 0):

Terminal Server itself can't help you here.

A proxy server is the way to go, but only if the users authenticate against it: otherwise it would only report many client connections from the same host, and you wouldn't be able to identify the actual user.

You can use a proxy server with domain authentication (like ISA Server) and configure it for users to automatically authenticate against it; otherwise, you need a proxy with its own authentication and a different user account for each one of your users.